# adding several edges simultaneously to a graph using igraph

Tags: r, igraph, edges

I would like to pass igraph a matrix of a series of edges for it to form between nodes. The edges are undirected. However, it is not adding the edges I would like for it to add

my graph looks like this

```
mygraph
IGRAPH U--- 30 11 -- 
+ attr: color (v/c), color (e/c)
+ edges:
[1]  3-- 4  3-- 9  4-- 5  4-- 6  6--10 12--14 15--20 16--21 25--27 25--30 26--29
```

I now want to add these undirected edges (edges in `m` go horizontally e.g. `12--13` is an edge, `9--13` is an edge, etc). If the edges are repeating they should be removed since it is undirected (meaning `23--20` is the same as `20--23`).

```
m
     value L1
[1,]     6  2
[2,]     4  5
[3,]     6  5
[4,]     2  6
[5,]    12 13
[6,]     9 13
[7,]    23 20
[8,]    20 23
```

when I do

```
add_edges(mygraph, m)
```

I get the following (note, the total number of edges is correct, but not the nodes that should have edges. For example, `12--13` does not exist and instead `12--9` is formed, which was not specified in `m`). It seems like `add_edges` is adding an edge vertically to make `12--9` instead of horizontally to make `12--13` from `m`

```
IGRAPH U--- 30 19 -- 
+ attr: color (v/c), color (e/c)
+ edges:
[1]  3-- 4  3-- 9  4-- 5  4-- 6  6--10 12--14 15--20 16--21 25--27 25--30 26--29  4-- 6  2-- 6  9--12 20--23  2-- 5  5-- 6 13--13
[19] 20--23
```

how can edges be added horizontally from a matrix to a graph using igraph?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a transpose of your edge matrix before adding them to your graph, the reason is that data in a matrix is stored by column, and it seems that `igraph` does not provide a proper interface for matrix, i.e, it doesn't interpret your matrix as by row edge matrix but just a vector and interpret each adjacent pair as a new edge:

Take a look at this simple example:

```
library(igraph)
mygraph <- graph(c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
mygraph
IGRAPH D--- 6 3 -- 
+ edges:
[1] 1->2 3->4 5->6

m <- matrix(c(6,2,4,5), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)
m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    2
[2,]    4    5
```

If I add m directly to the graph object:

```
add_edges(mygraph, m)
IGRAPH D--- 6 5 -- 
+ edges:
[1] 1->2 3->4 5->6 6->4 2->5
```

I have 6 -> 4 and 2 -> 5 added as graph, which is because:

```
as.vector(m)
# [1] 6 4 2 5
```

So adjacent nodes are interpreted as edges. But if you transpose `m` before adding it as edges, it gives the correct result.

```
add_edges(mygraph, t(m))
IGRAPH D--- 6 5 -- 
+ edges:
[1] 1->2 3->4 5->6 6->2 4->5
```